# Vetur configuration to respect eslint standard

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, eslint, prettier, vetur

I've set up a Vue.js project using vue-cli and work on it in VS Code and Vetur. ESLint is configured with the standard profile. I'd like the 'Format Document' command to produce a format which is valid for the eslint.

I've been able to solve the issue for single/double quotes and semi-columns with following `.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Now I'm trying to fix the issue, where no space is being added before method parenthesis:

- Definition `function ()` becomes `function()`
- Method call `showLoginDialog ()` becomes `showLoginDialog()`

I've tried changing the default formatter as described [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/226)

- Does a default `prettierrc` which respects eslint standard exist?
- If not, how can the above mentioned issue with spaces be fixed?

[edit] I've pushed the branch containing the .prettierrc.json config: https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/commit/acd93ab9e06e2e77849af7a346609ba6bf5d639c. The only part (I'm aware of) which doesn't work is the above mentioned issue with spaces between function and parenthesis? AFAICT this should have been taken care of with `"spaceBeforeFunctionParen": true` which doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am currently struggling with this too (i.e., formatting document formats vue/HTML OK, but removing spaces after function keyword).